# Information on Block Producers

Tags: block-producer

How would one programmatically obtain information on current BP’s as well as BP candidates? Information I would like:

A. Basic info

1. Website URL
2. Country
3. Location of servers
4. Server types (cloud vs bare metal, etc.)

B. Current Stats

1. Current number of votes
2. Current vote rank
3. How many voters?
4. List of top 10 voters
5. Transactions per second processed
6. Blocks per second processed

C. History

1. Down time
2. Previous vote rankings (and how long ranking maintained)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the producer list, including vote totals, in json form: `cleos system listproducers -j`

After you retrieve a producer's url from the list, fetch `bp.json` from that to get more information. e.g. `https://some-producer.io/bp.json`. The schema for `bp.json` [lives here](https://github.com/eosrio/bp-info-standard).

Some of the information you want, such as server type, isn't available on-chain or in `bp.json`. Some of it, such as blocks processed, requires digging through the block log.

Answer (score 1):

Because nodeos or keosd communicate in a REST way, they are available in the programming language.

In the example in the link below, there is an example of communicating with JavaScript.
https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the majority of that information from the following URLs:

https://eosportal.io/chain/12/producers

As well as: http://eosnetworkmonitor.io/

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking for a way to do this programmatically. Using cleos or a library or something.